# How to create a check between two attributes of two different tables

Tags: check-constraints

I have to create a check to know if the date in Livraison (Delivery in French) is >= Date in Commande (Order in French)

[image: Scheme]

I Hhad some issues on the SQL :

We did it in BonDeLivraison (DeliveryTicket in French):

```
CREATE TABLE BonDeLivraison (
NumeroBon INT NOT NULL  ,
IDClient INT NOT NULL ,
IDNumeroCde INT NOT NULL ,
AdresseLiv VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
CONSTRAINT un_bdl UNIQUE(NumeroBon),
CONSTRAINT cbdl PRIMARY KEY (NumeroBon) ,
CONSTRAINT FK_KEY_IDClient_BDL 
    FOREIGN KEY(IDClient) 
        REFERENCES Client (IDClient ) 
            ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT,
CONSTRAINT FK_KEY_IDNumeroCde_BDL 
    FOREIGN KEY(IDNumeroCde) 
        REFERENCES Commande (IDNumeroCde )
            ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT,
CHECK (
    (SELECT Date FROM Commande c WHERE IDNumeroCde = c.IDNumeroCde 
        AND IDClient = c.IDClient)
        > (SELECT Date FROM Livraison l WHERE 
            (SELECT * FROM ContenuBL b WHERE l.IDProduit = b.IDProduit
                AND l.NumeroBon = b.NumeroBon 
                    AND b.NumeroBon = NumeroBon
            )
           )
    )              
);
```

Comment: No, you can't have an `ASSERTION` (i.e. a constraint that affects more than 1 table) in current DBMS/SQL implementations. You'll have to have the 2 columns in the same table.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ thank you for your answer! Is there anyway to compare the two dates?

Comment: Is thewre a foreign key in `Livraison` that `REFERENCES BonDeLivraison` ?